# Error invoking "Configure Data Source...". Details: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio has an issue on a project that I've been working on for 8 years. Out of the blue, I now get the dreaded **error message** when configuring an Object Data Source for any page, new or existing, in my project. :

> "Error invoking "Configure Data Source...". Details: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

It's been a few years since I got this before and had to completely reinstall Windows, Visual Studio & 55 other applications to make the bug go away (this was VS 2010) - this takes about a week to do (!!!!).

Now, on VS 2015, I'm seeing this bug again, and, once again, I search the Internet for hours, but there are no solutions I can find.

Does anyone have any ideas (besides reinstalling everything again) to solve this mystery? Or where to look?

EDIT:
Creating the ObjectDataSource manually works fine, just no wizard.

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsEA" runat="server"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    SelectMethod="GetLinks"
    TypeName="EmailArchiveLinks.EmailArchiveLinkData"
    DataObjectTypeName="EmailArchiveLinks.EmailArchiveLink"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server, Access, Excel, CSV file?  I suspect you are using SQL Server and the database is not working correctly.  Try open up database with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.

Comment: SQL2014 - the database is working fine everywhere else. I can manually create the ObjectDataSource with no errors, just cannot use the wizard anymore.

Comment: So you can create the object.  Doesn't mean you can connect to server or the database in server isn't corrupted.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It connects to the SQL server fine. The entire solution and all its projects work fine, only the VS2015 wizard for ObjectDataSource is somehow corrupted, but with an ambiguous error like this, it's anyone's guess as to what is going on.

Comment: I can even connect to the database from within VS and see the tables, views, sps, etc. No security issues.
The questions are: What's the exception? What's the target? What's the invocation?

Comment: The connection to the database uses a virtual connection using a html port number.   So one think to try is to clear out your IE Browser history.  Another think to try is clearing out the c:\windows\temp folder. If your computer has been attacked by spyware these are the locations where the applications hide.  You may also want to use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark to see if you get any useful info or check the log files of the SQL Server.

Comment: No luck as of yet after clearing history and temp files. No errors in SQL, either.  I can configure other datasources, however.

Comment: It's definitely a problem with the project. I can create a new one and the ODS wizard works fine. Good news is that this rules out Visual Studio and Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, deleting some dlls in the bin folder did the trick. I deleted all  dlls that were no longer in use, cleaned and rebuilt the website. Go figure.

Comment: Deleting the dll would force reference projects to rebuild.  I often delete the bin folder when I have issues with compiler errors.  It will force all code to be rebuilt.

Comment: I should have said, deleting references, actually

Comment: I deleted all files in all bin folders. Brute force, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue after adding the SendGrid Package to my project. The issue is resolved temporarily when the SendGrid.dll is deleted from the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just running a clean worked for me.

Build->Clean Solution

[image]